# Advertising Computer Science Stack Exchange on other SE sites

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Graduated Stack Exchange sites display ads chosen by the community in the right-side bar. “Graduated” means sites that have been around for long enough to no longer be in beta, other than the original trilogy.

We could propose ads refering people to Computer Science SE. [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) would be good places to advertise, as well as [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) (but I guess we're well-known on TCS already), maybe others.

The constraints on these ads are:

- The ad must be provided as an image with mouseover text, nothing more. It links to a URL of our choice (presumably https://cs.stackexchange.com/ for us).
- The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

If we have a design, we can post it on the Community Promotion Ads threads ([cstheory](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2745/community-promotion-ads-2014), [math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11920/community-promotion-ads-2014), [programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6315/community-promotion-ads-2014), …)

For example, these are ads for [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) and [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/):

[image: Academia]                
[image: Crypto]

This is a **call for design**! Please propose images to advertise CS.SE.

Comment: fyi rs/I came up with a few ideas [oct 11 chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2710/2013/10/10) & rs asked for your opinion on one

Answer (score 5):

We threw some mock-ups through chat which may serve as starting point for discussion and/or inspiration. Be warned, lack of craftmanship ahead!

Any comments and/or proposals are welcome.

#### For programming sites

[image]
[image]
[image: The Landau terms are racing against each other]

#### For other sites

[image]

Comment: Where trees grow down? An average user would think it's Australia.SE.

Comment: @DeerHunter Those we don't want here.

Comment: Ad upvoters: which ideas do you like and would want to see expanded upon? What ideas do you have?

Answer (score 4):

[image: Operating Systems Principles on CS.SE]

Comment: This one might be good on superuser.com and/or unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks! It's almost the end of the year, but [let's give it a go](https://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/community-promotion-ads-2014/3271#3271). I've linked it to [tag:operating-systems], I think it makes more sense.

Comment: Can we visually indicate (in the background) that we deal with all the buddies at once? Also, my gut says that "Principles and Design of Operating Systems" would be preferable. Myself, I'd say "Principles and Theory" and avoid "Design" because I'm sure practitioners will understand it differently from us, but ymmv.

Comment: @Gilles, wait, wait!  The reason I brought this up now is that _next year's_ Community Promotion Meta Posts will be made some time in the next couple of weeks.  Putting it on this year's doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Recursion jokes on CS.SE]

Comment: I'm pretty sure [cs.se] will graduate well before [french.se]…

Comment: So the Matisse joke/reference just isn't working.

Comment: I know the reference but I don't think many people will recognize it, especially if they don't speak French.

Comment: agreed on the french thing, needs english, and a pipe? sherlock holmes? anyway +1 for the effort

Comment: So the Matisse reference *really* isn't working, @vzn.

Comment: _???_ matisse is a _painter_

Comment: Magritte.  Mattise was a typo.  Magritte is also a painter.  He painted a picture of a pipe that says _Ceci n'est pas une pipe_, (in English: _this is not a pipe_). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images It's a famous self-referential joke.  Anyway: my attempt to turn it into a whimsical advertisement for cs.se just didn't work.  Downvote away!!!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Programming Language Design and Implementation on CS.SE]

Comment: This one might be good on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Although I think only academics who've used the [dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Compiler_Design) to teach a compilers course will get the dragon reference, so maybe it would only work on cstheory.se.

Comment: "Implementation" needs to go, and you need some "padding" along the border.

Comment: @Raphael: Maybe "Principles of Programming Languages"?  (That way it is still the name of a conference, and a more theoretical conference at that.)

Comment: Sounds good! (Also, POPL, tihihi...)