# New Site Design!

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Congratulations! Thank you for your [valuable design feedback](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/computer-science-new-site-design).

We have also themed the [twitter account](https://twitter.com/stackcompsci) and newsletter template for this site, and adjusted the privilege levels to higher thresholds.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug".

Congrats again and thank you for being an awesome community!

Oh! And by the way, we have also updated your [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science) theme!

Comment: Quick feedback: 1) Overall like it, thanks! 2) [[obsolete](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/what-should-be-the-alignment-of-titles)] 3) Like the font(s)! 4) [[obsolete](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/about-the-new-badge-icons)]

Comment: Somehow the new front page is difficult for my eyes. Too little contrast? Could we simply have e.g. unread questions in 100% black, instead of the current greenish-bluish shade?

Comment: However I love the new design. Bravo @Paweł

Comment: I second Jukka on contrast. It would be kinder on our eyes. The design looks modern and great by the way, it will take some time to get used to it and avoid being distracted by it. :)

Comment: The centered titles have gotten a bad reception. Since I think there may be a reasonable middle ground, I created [a small vote with four versions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1214/98). Please head over there, vote and express your opinion in the comments. [Removing all comments about title alignment now.]

Comment: @Raphael sure, no problem. now the question is: should we wait till voting is over (if yes, how long it gonna take?) or implement left-aligned titles anyway?

Comment: @Paweł Your choice; I think the feedback was quite unequivocal (if voiced by few). If you think you have enough grounds to switch to the safe standards, I'm not against that. If you want to wait for a community decision, that's fine as well. (You are right, I should set a deadline. Will ask my fellow mods and then edit the other question.)

Comment: (Please ignore me, I just felt that ) The design looks cool in it's "black & white" state in meta, than "color"ed in the main site.

Comment: @Paweł Did you change the fonts with today's update?

Comment: I was looking at other SE sites and I think what you have done here is among the very best site designs. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 10):

I just wanted to congratulate you on this design. You did an awesome job on a difficult topic, and you were very responsive to the community's input. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Just a minor comment. I like the badges noted as nodes in a tree in the user's overview, but why not make the silver badge a internal node with two children, and why have all arcs pointing in the same direction?

Comment: 1) Gold should (arguably) look like "more" than silver. Giving silver more edges creates the inverse impression. (Which was one reason why gold was updated to have two edges.) 2) Badges have a maximum size given by a square. If you attach edges not pointing towards the corners, you have to have a smaller circles or shorter edges. Both would impede recognition.

Answer (score 2):

Overall, it looks it neat, except:

1. Too much wasted white space (common to many SE websites)
2. As said in comments, the font color is too light, I feel like taking my sunglasses.

E.g. compare:

[image]

vs

[image]

(This issue isn't restricted to this website: [Internet is Becoming Unreadable Because of a Trend Towards Lighter, Thinner Fonts](https://science.slashdot.org/story/16/10/24/1716222/internet-is-becoming-unreadable-because-of-a-trend-towards-lighter-thinner-fonts))

Comment: Questions lists are a little on the low-contrast side of things, true. I for one don't have any trouble reading them even with display brightness tuned down.