# What should be the alignment of titles?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

Our pretty new design has gotten [bad feedback](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/new-site-design) regarding centered question titles from several users.

Paweł already said he's going to change them back to the more standard left alignment, but I think the middle-ground version is worth looking at. Plus, I think the feedback should be collected in proper form, and not just as a bunch of comments mixed with other feedback.

Therefore I have mocked three versions; please vote on which you prefer, and add other variants I have missed. Thanks!

The vote was open until February 5th, 23:59 GMT (plus the time it took me to wake up and think of checking here). We've notified Paweł of the result.

---

Vote count (Feb 6th, 12:25 GMT):

- Left-aligned, breaking before sidebar: +18/-2
- Left-aligned: +12/-0
- Centered over text: +3/-6
- Bouncing marquee: +2/-6
- Centered: +1/-10

Comment: Does the impression change with longer titles, in particular such that overflow?

Comment: Longest titles on the site: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35190/understanding-reductions-would-a-polynomial-time-algorithm-for-one-np-complete and http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42852/can-a-relatively-small-subset-of-random-numbers-be-permuted-and-reused-and-still

Comment: @Gilles Thanks, added pictures. Wow, long titles are crappy with either solution.

Comment: @Paweł Looks like we have a clear winner.

Comment: Yeap, this should be live on Monday.

Comment: @Paweł Much better, thank you!

Answer (score 18):

#### Left-aligned, breaking before the sidebar

Even with left-alignment, we may not want titled to flow over the sidebar:

[image]

[image]

Reproduce by combinging `text-align : left;` with `padding : 8px 320px 11px 20px;` on `div#question-header`.

Comment: I think the whitespace left for long titles is wasted. Long titles are bad in every of the variants, but using the space above the sidebar can help save vertical space at least.

Comment: Most long titles barely overflow into the area above the sidebar, which is why I don't like the fact that just one word would break to the next line in that case if this design is implemented.

Comment: @brandaemon I guess that's true for *any* breaking point. We'd have to look at the distribution of title lengths to see if such events are more or less likely with longer or shorter title areas.

Answer (score 13):

#### Left-aligned

The network standard (the distance from the left border may have to be tweaked):

[image]

[image]

Reproduce with changing `div#question-header` to `text-align : left;`.

Comment: Title over the sidebar looks weird. Well, long titles are bad in every of the variants, but using the space above the sidebar can help save vertical space at least (compare with [the alternative](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1218/98)).

Comment: This is the format that Stack Overflow uses, although that doesn't necessarily mean it's the best.

Answer (score -2):

#### Centered over the text

A quick mock (adding 300px to the right padding to account for the sidebar):

[image]

[image]

Reproduce with changing `div#question-header` to `padding : 8px 320px 11px 20px;`; note how the right padding gains 300px, exactly the width of the sidebar.

Comment: This is far less weird than the "center over everything" variant, but there is lots of wasted space with long titles.

Comment: For titles that are short, this looks really good in my unpopular opinion. But long.. gross..

Comment: @Insane That's my impression, too.

Answer (score -5):

#### In a marquee, bouncing between left and right

This seems like a reasonable compromise between center, left and right alignment.

[image]

Comment: <shudder> <whimper> <croak>

Comment: I *do* hope this was intended as satire.

Comment: I pissed myself laughing at this.

Comment: @Insane Were you around when the internet *actually* looked like that? I mainly got scared. o.o

Comment: @Raphael I was around, but not old enough to be viewing the pages!

Comment: There is one thing missing - it does not blink :-/

Answer (score -9):

#### Centered

The current version:

[image]

[image]

Reproduce: leave `div#question-header` with `text-align : center;`.

Comment: This one I like the least.