# Button color in chat provides no contrast

Tags: bug, status-planned, design, chat

The buttons in chat are colored so that

1. they are hardly visible over the background and

   [image]
2. the logo is hardly visible on the button(s).

   [image]

A point can be made for solving 1) by using the b/w version of the background in chat (which may take some of the color-saturation punch out of it), but that does not solve 2). So I move for using a different color for the buttons.

Comment: @Paweł Any news on this and [this related](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/site-logo-in-chat-looks-out-of-place) proposal/bug?

Comment: not yet guys, sory :((( but i keep it in mind and will get to this at some point!

Comment: @Paweł It's been a while. Any news?

Answer (score 3):

The current button color is using #1 from [the palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A82EC.png) as [proposed in the design feedback thread](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/computer-science-new-site-design).

Here is how it would look using #2 (#227277):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The current button color is using #1 from [the palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A82EC.png) as [proposed in the design feedback thread](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/computer-science-new-site-design).

Here is how it would look using #6 (`#0e5870`):

[image]
[image]

Comment: The darkest of the teal variants, this is my runner-up.

Answer (score 1):

The current button color is using #1 from [the palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A82EC.png) as [proposed in the design feedback thread](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/computer-science-new-site-design).

Here is how it would look using #3 (`#308e9c`):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The current button color is using #1 from [the palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A82EC.png) as [proposed in the design feedback thread](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/computer-science-new-site-design).

Here is how it would look using #4 (`#748c8f`):

[image]
[image]

Comment: This may be my favorite. I think an even darker grey would be better, though.