# Site logo in chat looks out of place

Tags: bug, design, chat

In the lower-right corner of chat we find the site logo:

[image]

With the white rectangle, this looks awfully out of place. A different version should be used.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution was given in the [design proposal thread](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/computer-science-new-site-design) and is featured on every page:

[image]

And the SVG sprite should probably be used there (currently it's a PNG).