# Meaning of Computer Science stackexchange icon - logo

Tags: discussion

I just fount that the [icon](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/cs/img/logo.svg) of the Computer Science community of stackexchange is very similar to a tree of a problem I'm dealing with.

Does anybody know whether this represent some well known problem or something? or could it be just a coincidence?

Thanks all, folks!

Comment: https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1169/1636

Comment: Okay, I see. So it seems like a nice looking tree at the end of the day. 
It is interesting though, that this particular tree shows up in many applications, such as in Huffman codes.

Comment: Binary trees are one of the fundamental "non-elementary" data structures in CS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inspirations towards a logo for cs.SE](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1169/inspirations-towards-a-logo-for-cs-se)